# Has the external knit product been used to construct a previously unknown group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, soft-question, big-list

In the Wikipedia article
[Zappa–Szép product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zappa%E2%80%93Sz%C3%A9p_product)
, the knit product (a.k.a. Zappa–Szép product, Zappa–Rédei-Szép product, general product, exact factorization) is defined, and its basic properties are laid out.  Within that article lies a section entitled "External Zappa–Szép products" which details how to take groups $H$ and $K$ (when the groups meet certain properties and when certain functions $H\times K\rightarrow H$ and $H\times K\rightarrow K$ are defined) and **define** a multiplication on the Cartesian product $H\times K$, resulting in a group which can be seen to be the internal knit product of subgroups $H\times 1$ and $1\times K$, thus constructing the external knit product.  The external version, though, looks to be rather unwieldy to use in practice, and this brings me to my question.

*Was a group ever **discovered** via the external knit product construction, that otherwise was previously unknown and where neither subgroup was normal?*

It is quite likely a real pain to construct the left and right actions (i.e., the aforementioned functions $H\times K\rightarrow *$) and then show all caveats are met, without *a priori* having a group there to serve as the roadmap.  Hence, if this actually has happened, say to construct a counterexample to a given conjecture, then studying how the conjecture gave rise to the actions would be (for me, at least) a fascinating study.

As an aside, there are plenty of examples wherein a group factors as an internal knit product of subgroups, neither of which is normal.  In fact, given an arbitrary group $G$, a Frattini argument applied to the right regular action of $G$ on itself provides a knit product factorization of the symmetric group ${\rm Sym}(G)$ as $G$ times ${\rm Sym}(G\smallsetminus 1)$.  Thus, all but the smallest such groups $G$ provide the specified factorizations.

Comment: There is a related kind of situation. I am thinking of the Kegel-Wielandt Theorem, which asserts that if a finite group $G$ has a factorization $G = AB$ with $A,B$ nilpotent, then $G$ is solvable. Here, one knows nothing else a priori about  $G,$ except that  it has a special factorization. This could be seen as a non--existence theorem (ie, a non-solvable group can't have such a factorization). While it is not assumed that $A \cap B = 1,$ the most interesting case is when $A$ and $B$ have coprime orders.

Comment: I've never seen any such construction. Actually I have always found all this "product" terminology a bit presumptuous and "exact factorization" (or "knit factorization") better reflects what it is.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson It's worth pointing out it is still unknown whether the Kegel-Wielandt Theorem generalizes to infinite groups, although it has been proved in a number of special cases.